# Magento 2:Modal window not working in Product edit page

Tags: magento2, backend, modal-popup

I am trying to create custom tab and have a button which on click its trigger modal window, I tried to create by following this method:https://www.mageworx.com/blog/2016/08/how-to-create-a-modal-window-in-a-custom-field-with-a-code-in-magento-2/

It is not showing any error, I also check logs but it shows nothing and even my custom tab is not displaying on the product edit page.

My di.xml

```
 <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
     <type name="SimpleMagento\ProductCustomerPrice\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\ProductPrice">
        <arguments>
           <argument name="scopeName" xsi:type="string">product_form.product_form</argument>
        </arguments>
     </type>
     <virtualType name="SimpleMagento\ProductCustomerPrice\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Pool" type="Magento\Ui\DataProvider\Modifier\Pool">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="modifiers" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="related" xsi:type="array">
                   <item name="class" xsi:type="string">SimpleMagento\ProductCustomerPrice\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\ProductPrice</item>
                   <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">110</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
       </arguments>
    </virtualType>
</config>
```

File: ProductPrice.php

File Path:

> SimpleMagento\ProductCustomerPrice\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\ProductPrice

```
class ProductPrice extends \Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\AbstractModifier
{
const CUSTOM_MODAL_LINK = 'custom_modal_link';
const CUSTOM_MODAL_INDEX = 'custom_modal';
const CUSTOM_MODAL_CONTENT = 'content';
const CUSTOM_MODAL_FIELDSET = 'fieldset';
const CONTAINER_HEADER_NAME = 'header';
/**
 * @var LocatorInterface
 */
protected $locator;
/**
 * @var UrlInterface
 */
protected $urlBuilder;
/**
 * @var string
 */
protected $scopeName;
/**
 * @var string
 */
protected $scopePrefix;
/**
 * @var string
 */
private static $previousGroup = 'search-engine-optimization';

/**
 * @var int
 */
private static $sortOrder = 90;

public function __construct(LocatorInterface $locator,
                            UrlInterface $urlBuilder,
                            $scopeName = '',
                            $scopePrefix = '')
{
    $this->locator = $locator;
    $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
    $this->scopeName = $scopeName;
    $this->scopePrefix = $scopePrefix;
}

/**
 * @param array $data
 * @return array
 * @since 100.1.0
 */
public function modifyData(array $meta)
{
  return $meta;
}

/**
 * @param array $meta
 * @return array
 * @since 100.1.0
 */
public function modifyMeta(array $meta)
{
    $this->meta = $meta;
    $this->addCustomModal();
    $this->addCustomModalLink(10);

    return $this->meta;
}

protected function addCustomModal()
{
    $this->meta = array_merge_recursive(
        $this->meta,
        [
            static::CUSTOM_MODAL_INDEX => $this->getModalConfig(),
        ]
    );
}

protected function getModalConfig()
{
    return [
        'arguments' => [
            'data' => [
                'config' => [
                    'componentType' => Modal::NAME,
                    'dataScope' => '',
                    'provider' => static::FORM_NAME . '.product_form_data_source',
                    'ns' => static::FORM_NAME,
                    'options' => [
                        'title' => __('Modal Title'),
                        'buttons' => [
                            [
                                'text' => __('Save'),
                                'class' => 'action-primary', // additional class
                                'actions' => [
                                    [
                                        'targetName' => 'index = product_form', // Element selector
                                        'actionName' => 'save', // Save parent form (product)
                                    ],
                                    'closeModal', // method name
                                ],
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'children' => [
            static::CUSTOM_MODAL_CONTENT => [
                'arguments' => [
                    'data' => [
                        'config' => [
                            'autoRender' => false,
                            'componentType' => 'container',
                            'dataScope' => 'data.product', // save data in the product data
                            'externalProvider' => 'data.product_data_source',
                            'ns' => static::FORM_NAME,
                            'render_url' => $this->urlBuilder->getUrl('mui/index/render'),
                            'realTimeLink' => true,
                            'behaviourType' => 'edit',
                            'externalFilterMode' => true,
                            'currentProductId' => $this->locator->getProduct()->getId(),
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
                'children' => [
                    static::CUSTOM_MODAL_FIELDSET => [
                        'arguments' => [
                            'data' => [
                                'config' => [
                                    'label' => __('Fieldset'),
                                    'componentType' => Fieldset::NAME,
                                    'dataScope' => 'custom_data',
                                    'collapsible' => true,
                                    'sortOrder' => 10,
                                    'opened' => true,
                                ],
                            ],
                        ],
                        'children' => [
                            static::CONTAINER_HEADER_NAME => $this->getHeaderContainerConfig(10),
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ];
}

protected function getHeaderContainerConfig($sortOrder)
{
    return [
        'arguments' => [
            'data' => [
                'config' => [
                    'label' => null,
                    'formElement' => Container::NAME,
                    'componentType' => Container::NAME,
                    'template' => 'ui/form/components/complex',
                    'sortOrder' => $sortOrder,
                    'content' => __('You can write any text here'),
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'children' => [],
    ];
}
protected function addCustomModalLink($sortOrder)
{
    $this->meta = array_replace_recursive(
        $this->meta,
        [
            CustomOptions::GROUP_CUSTOM_OPTIONS_NAME => [
                'children' => [
                    CustomOptions::CONTAINER_HEADER_NAME => [
                        'children' => [
                            static::CUSTOM_MODAL_LINK => [
                                'arguments' => [
                                    'data' => [
                                        'config' => [
                                            'title' => __('Open Custom Modal'),
                                            'formElement' => Container::NAME,
                                            'componentType' => Container::NAME,
                                            'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/components/button',
                                            'actions' => [
                                                [
                                                    'targetName' => 'ns=' . static::FORM_NAME . ', index='
                                                        . static::CUSTOM_MODAL_INDEX, // selector
                                                    'actionName' => 'openModal', // method name
                                                ],
                                            ],
                                            'displayAsLink' => false,
                                            'sortOrder' => $sortOrder,
                                        ],
                                    ],
                                ],
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ]
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: As I know there is a default  modifier called **related**. Try to change the name in modifier argument from```<item name="related" xsi:type="array">``` to the ```<item name="myCustomModal" xsi:type="array">```. And please be sure this **di.xml** is placed inside **etc/adminhtml** directory

Comment: And the name of the VirtualType you would like to apply the modifier should be ```name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Pool"```. And do not pass **type** argument for VirtualType because it is passed inside Magento_Catalog's di.xml

Comment: @durex, its in etc/adminhtml, btw nothings change after I make changes as per your suggestion

Comment: So I sure you have some mistakes here, I've tested the code and everything you've made works. Take a look at the screenshots I've attached in the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly recommend reading the Magento's docs about the Ui Components [here at the Magento Docs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/ui_comp_guide/concepts/ui_comp_config_flow_concept.html).

You were trying to put the modal button tab inside *Customizable Options* section so please check the *addCustomModalLink* function to understand how to add a custom section.

Also this works only with the Magento 2.2 as I know, when the modifiers support for the Product Form was added.

Be sure your module is enabled inside the global *etc/config.php*.

There is a default modifier called *related*. Try to change the name in modifier argument from `<item name="related" xsi:type="array">` to the `<item name="myCustomModal" xsi:type="array">`.

And please be sure this *di.xml* is placed inside *etc/adminhtml* directory.

And the name of the VirtualType you would like to apply the modifier should be `name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Pool"`. And do not pass type argument for VirtualType because it is passed inside Magento_Catalog's di.xml. Also I don't think you need to pass scopeName argument inside your modifier because you don't use it.

The full code is:

*app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml/di.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <virtualType name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Pool">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="modifiers" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="myCustomModifier" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Product\Modifier\Modifier</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">110</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
</config>
```

*app/code/Vendor/Module/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Product/Modifier/Modifier.php*

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Product\Modifier;

use Magento\Backend\Model\UrlInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Locator\LocatorInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\AbstractModifier;
use Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\CustomOptions;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Container;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Fieldset;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Modal;

class Modifier extends AbstractModifier
{
    const CUSTOM_MODAL_LINK = 'custom_modal_link';
    const CUSTOM_MODAL_INDEX = 'custom_modal';
    const CUSTOM_MODAL_CONTENT = 'content';
    const CUSTOM_MODAL_FIELDSET = 'fieldset';
    const CONTAINER_HEADER_NAME = 'header';
    const CUSTOM_GROUP_NAME = 'my_custom_group';
    const CUSTOM_GROUP_BTN_CONTAINER_NAME = 'my_buttons';
    /**
     * @var LocatorInterface
     */
    protected $locator;
    /**
     * @var UrlInterface
     */
    protected $urlBuilder;
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $scopeName;
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $scopePrefix;
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private static $previousGroup = 'search-engine-optimization';

    /**
     * @var int
     */
    private static $sortOrder = 90;

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $meta = [];

    /**
     * Modifier constructor.
     * @param LocatorInterface $locator
     * @param UrlInterface $urlBuilder
     */
    public function __construct(
        LocatorInterface $locator,
        UrlInterface $urlBuilder
    ) {
        $this->locator = $locator;
        $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
    }

    /**
     * @param array $data
     * @return array
     * @since 100.1.0
     */
    public function modifyData(array $data)
    {
        return $data;
    }

    /**
     * @param array $meta
     * @return array
     * @since 100.1.0
     */
    public function modifyMeta(array $meta)
    {
        $this->meta = $meta;
        $this->addCustomModal();
        $this->addCustomModalLink(1000);

        return $this->meta;
    }

    /**
     * @return void
     */
    protected function addCustomModal()
    {
        $this->meta = array_merge_recursive(
            $this->meta,
            [
                static::CUSTOM_MODAL_INDEX => $this->getModalConfig(),
            ]
        );
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getModalConfig()
    {
        return [
            'arguments' => [
                'data' => [
                    'config' => [
                        'componentType' => Modal::NAME,
                        'dataScope' => '',
                        'provider' => static::FORM_NAME . '.product_form_data_source',
                        'ns' => static::FORM_NAME,
                        'options' => [
                            'title' => __('Modal Title'),
                            'buttons' => [
                                [
                                    'text' => __('Save'),
                                    'class' => 'action-primary', // additional class
                                    'actions' => [
                                        [
                                            'targetName' => 'index = product_form', // Element selector
                                            'actionName' => 'save', // Save parent form (product)
                                        ],
                                        'closeModal', // method name
                                    ],
                                ],
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'children' => [
                static::CUSTOM_MODAL_CONTENT => [
                    'arguments' => [
                        'data' => [
                            'config' => [
                                'autoRender' => false,
                                'componentType' => 'container',
                                'dataScope' => 'data.product', // save data in the product data
                                'externalProvider' => 'data.product_data_source',
                                'ns' => static::FORM_NAME,
                                'render_url' => $this->urlBuilder->getUrl('mui/index/render'),
                                'realTimeLink' => true,
                                'behaviourType' => 'edit',
                                'externalFilterMode' => true,
                                'currentProductId' => $this->locator->getProduct()->getId(),
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                    'children' => [
                        static::CUSTOM_MODAL_FIELDSET => [
                            'arguments' => [
                                'data' => [
                                    'config' => [
                                        'label' => __('Fieldset'),
                                        'componentType' => Fieldset::NAME,
                                        'dataScope' => 'custom_data',
                                        'collapsible' => true,
                                        'sortOrder' => 10,
                                        'opened' => true,
                                    ],
                                ],
                            ],
                            'children' => [
                                static::CONTAINER_HEADER_NAME => $this->getHeaderContainerConfig(10),
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @param $sortOrder
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getHeaderContainerConfig($sortOrder)
    {
        return [
            'arguments' => [
                'data' => [
                    'config' => [
                        'label' => null,
                        'formElement' => Container::NAME,
                        'componentType' => Container::NAME,
                        'template' => 'ui/form/components/complex',
                        'sortOrder' => $sortOrder,
                        'content' => __('You can write any text here'),
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'children' => [],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @param $sortOrder
     * @return void
     */
    protected function addCustomModalLink($sortOrder)
    {
        $this->meta = array_replace_recursive(
            $this->meta,
            [
                static::CUSTOM_GROUP_NAME => [
                    'arguments' => [
                        'data' => [
                            'config' => [
                                'label' => __('My Group Fieldset'),
                                'componentType' => Fieldset::NAME,
                                'collapsible' => true,
                                'sortOrder' => $sortOrder,
                                'opened' => true,
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                    'children' => [
                        self::CUSTOM_GROUP_BTN_CONTAINER_NAME => [
                            'arguments' => [
                                'data' => [
                                    'config' => [
                                        'label' => null,
                                        'formElement' => Container::NAME,
                                        'componentType' => Container::NAME,
                                        'template' => 'ui/form/components/complex',
                                        'sortOrder' => 10,
                                        'content' => __('There are your buttons inside children section.'),
                                    ],
                                ],
                            ],
                            'children' => [
                                static::CUSTOM_MODAL_LINK => [
                                    'arguments' => [
                                        'data' => [
                                            'config' => [
                                                'title' => __('Open Custom Modal'),
                                                'formElement' => Container::NAME,
                                                'componentType' => Container::NAME,
                                                'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/components/button',
                                                'actions' => [
                                                    [
                                                        'targetName' => 'ns=' . static::FORM_NAME . ', index='
                                                            . static::CUSTOM_MODAL_INDEX, // selector
                                                        'actionName' => 'openModal', // method name
                                                    ],
                                                ],
                                                'displayAsLink' => false,
                                                'sortOrder' => 10,
                                            ],
                                        ],
                                    ],
                                ],
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

*app/code/Vendor/Module/registration.php*

```
<?php

use \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;

ComponentRegistrar::register(ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, 'Vendor_Module', __DIR__);
```

*app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/module.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Module"/>
</config>
```

There are screenshots.

[image: The button]

[image: The modal]

Comment: app/code/Vendor/Module/DataProvider/Ui/Product/Form/Product/Modifier/Modifier.php, are you sure regarding this path? I think Ui/DataProvider will be right

Comment: @SagarParikhSGR Oh sorry I accidentally mixed up it with _DataProvider_ and _Ui_. The correct path is ```app/code/Vendor/Module/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Product/Modifier/Modifier.php```

Comment: You can place it whatever you want though. Just don't forget to change the namespace and the declaration of it inside di.xml

Comment: but why the button show in customizable options?  I am try to create custom tab and if someone open the tab, its shows the button for the popup window, a similar feature like `Related Products, Up-Sells, and Cross-Sells` tab

Comment: I understand I follow the wrong tutorial for it, can you please help for how I can achieve this functionality ?

Comment: I created custom tab following this: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/218907/how-to-add-tab-in-product-edit-page-in-magento2, but its phtml so I don't how can I create popup model using ui component

Comment: Because you use ```CustomOptions::GROUP_CUSTOM_OPTIONS_NAME``` container name as the parent container for the modal button.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103568/discussion-between-sagar-parikh-sgr-and-durex).

Comment: I've changed the answer. Please look up the last function ```addCustomModalLink``` to understand how to create a new section on the product edit form.

Comment: working like charm :)